# Ansible: How to copy output of 4 commands

Tags: ansible

I would like to copy the content of the variable showoutput (in which there are 4 commands) in a file. But, when I execute my playbook, It copy only the first one command.

How to copy the four commands ?

Below my playbook:

```
- hosts: ios
  vars:
    command_list:
      - show cdp neigh
      - show ip interface brief
      - show clock
      - show arp

  tasks:
    - name: Run the SHOW commands and save output
      ios_command:
        commands: "{{ command_list }}"
      register: showoutput

    - name : Copy the result in a file
      copy:
        content: "{{showoutput.stdout[0]}}"
        dest: "/home/net/output/{{hostvars.localhost.DTG}}/{{inventory_hostname}}-{{hostvars.localhost.DTG}}-test.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansible's documentation on [Registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables),

> When you register a variable in a task with a loop, the registered
>   variable contains a value for each item in the loop. The data
>   structure placed in the variable during the loop will contain a
>   `results` attribute, that is a list of all responses from the module.

The output of each command should be available in `showoutput.results` which is an array. You can loop over them as

```
    - name : Copy the result in a file
      copy:
        content: "{{ item.stdout }}"
        dest: "/home/net/output/{{hostvars.localhost.DTG}}/{{inventory_hostname}}-{{hostvars.localhost.DTG}}-test.txt"
      with_items: "{{ showoutput.results }}"
```